# I want to perform all of these mongoose querieis in one transaction with the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model

I am working on a project in node js and I have this model that requires multiple cascaded inserts on creation like illustrated in the code below.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const member = require("./team_member")
const roles = require("./team_roles")
const channel_service = require("../../services/channel_service")

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, //add unique check
        unique: true,
    },
    team_owner: {
        type: String
    },
    team_owner_id: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["USER", "TEAM"]
    }
})

schema.post("save", async function (doc, next) {
    try {
        const instances = await roles.insertMany([
            { title: "Admin", team: doc.name, team_id: doc.id, permissions: {} },
            { title: "Guest", team: doc.name, team_id: doc.id, permissions: {} }
        ])
        await member.create({ 
            user: doc.team_owner,
            user_id : doc.team_owner_id, 
            team: doc.name, 
            team_id: doc.id, 
            roles: [{ 
                title: instances[0].title, 
                id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(instances[0].id) 
            } ,
            {
                title: instances[1].title, 
                id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(instances[1].id) 
            }]
        })
        await channel_service.insert_many([
            { title : "Members", team : doc.id, role_restricted : [instances[0].id]},
            { title : "Roles", team : doc.id, role_restricted : [instances[0].id]}
        ])
        next()
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }
    next()
})

const team = mongoose.model("team", schema)

module.exports = team
```

What I want to do is to minimize all of these db pings to one single send off like the following pseudo code

```
const arr = [query1, query2, query3, ...]
db.commit(arr)
```

I am not aware of anything that does this on the mongoose documentations. The closest thing is `model.bulkInsert(data)` but that requires that requires that you specify which model you're using so you're still going to open a new transaction with the database if you have insertions on multiple models.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html